# How to specify the word-breaking conditions in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Specifically, say I have a string like ABC-123-NNN. I would like the paragraph to have line breaks, but **not** to break at the dashes.

i.e. if my text is "The serial number ABC-123-NNN is not valid", I would like to keep together the entire serial number if it exceeds the container width.

So the following is ok:

```
  The serial number 
  ABC-123-NNN is not 
  valid
```

But the following (which is the behavior of IE6) is not:

```
  The serial number ABC-
  123-NNN is not valid
```

Currently IE seems to break at dashes. Is there any applicable CSS or whatever I can apply to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix in IE: wrap your text in < NOBR > tags, and then use the < WBR > tag to indicate a break:

```
<nobr>The serial number<wbr /> ABC-123-NNN is not<wbr /> valid</nobr>
```

or to just make sure that the serial number is intact:

```
The serial number <nobr>ABC-123-NNN</nobr> is not valid
```

Note that this method is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [non-breaking hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm).

```
ABC&#x2011;123&#x2011;NNN
```

Comment: Great find, bdonlan. What if the serial number contains spaces though?

Comment: Use a non-breaking space then (&nbsp;)

Comment: +1 for finding something that will be very useful for me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use the <nobr> tag around the serial number